# Backbone views not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, html5-canvas

I am making an application where the user should be able to click on an element, then that same element must be rendered inside another HTML division. The problem is, that the behaviour of the clicking event is chaotic and the result does not go as expected.

I am doing this with backbone.js models, collections and views. Any ideas on how could this be fixed for a proper behaviour?

Here is the code I am trying to get to work: http://jsfiddle.net/rpKbM/

Comment: "same element must be rendered inside another HTML division". Here Which another division you are talking ?

Comment: Looking at the code, there are three canvases in div#boxes, each one with a different color square. Everytime you click on one of this canvases, that same canvas should appear inside div#new. For example, if you click the red square, a red square should appear in div#new, while leaving untouched the div#boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the `el` instance when you're creating your new `canvas`. Try the following and should work as expected (it will create a new element instead of moving the current one):

```
canvas.click(function() {
  var newview = new BoxView({
    tagName: 'canvas', //Instead of el: canvas
    model: model
  });
$("#new").html(newview.render());
});
```

And here is a corrected and working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpKbM/3/)

Comment: Thanks @Alladinian, that worked fine. Just did not get the difference between tagName and el, in the backbone reference it is not clearly stated, can you please give me a quick review of these two?

Comment: In your code you are doing: `var el = $(this.el);` which means that `el` now refers to the specific instance of this element. By using `tagName` on the other hand, you're telling backbone to create a new (`canvas` in your example) element instead. I hope that this makes sense :)

Comment: Also a general rule would be: You use `el` to bind a backbone view to an _existing_ element and `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` to create a new one.